SQLAlchemy async Records are not added to the association table
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
There is this code. Tables are created, model tables
are filled, everything works. But records are not added to the association table.
The code completes without errors, but the drugs_diseases table is empty.
models.py
# Association table
drugs_diseases = Table(
    "drugs_diseases",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("drug_id", ForeignKey("drugs.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("disease_id", ForeignKey("diseases.id"), primary_key=True),
)

class Disease(Base):
    __tablename__ = "diseases"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    drugs = relationship("Drug", secondary=drugs_diseases, back_populates="diseases")

class Drug(Base):
    __tablename__ = "drugs"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    diseases = relationship("Disease", secondary=drugs_diseases, back_populates="drugs")

orm_query.py
async def orm_get_drug(
    async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession], name: str
) -> Drug:
    async with async_session() as session:
        query = select(Drug).where(Drug.name == name)
        drug = await session.scalar(query)
        await session.refresh(drug, attribute_names=["diseases"])

        return drug

async def orm_get_disease(
        async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession], name: str
) -> Disease:
    async with async_session() as session:
        query = select(Disease).where(Disease.name == name)
        disease = await session.scalar(query)
        await session.refresh(disease, attribute_names=["drugs"])

        return disease

async def orm_add_drug_disease(
        async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession], name_drug: str, name_disease
) -> None:
    async with async_session() as session:
        drug = await orm_get_drug(async_session, name_drug)
        disease = await orm_get_disease(async_session, name_disease)

        drug.diseases.append(disease)
        await session.commit()

I'm trying to add an entry to the association table. The code completes without errors, but the entry is not added to the association table.
main.py
...
# "Analgin" is already in the Drug table and "Toothache" is in Disease
await orm_add_drug_disease(session_maker, "Analgin", "Toothache")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


What does Base.metadata do? How have you created the Object metadata? There could be several reasons, why it’s not working. You should share a minimal reproducable example.

Base.metadata says that the class inherits from Base. The same code works completely in synchronous mode and the association tables are filled correctly. In asynchronous, the main tables are filled and the code completes without errors, but the association table remains empty. That is, the orm_add_drug_disease function does not work.
